# Stored procedure results to multiple excel sheets of same workbook using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have to export the SQL server data to Multiple sheets of same workbook. 
This is my requirement.

I have 3 select stored procedure (I am using SQL server 2014) and each stored procedure will return 3 different data sets. I need to export these 3 result sets in to 3 different sheets of same excel file. (For example, Sheet1 contains result sets of stored procedure 1, Sheet2 contains result sets of stored procedure 2 and Sheet3 contains result sets of stored procedure 3).

How can I do this? I will have to schedule this process in sql server agent

I have tried the below code but it did not work for me.

```
insert into OPENROWSET(
   'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
   'Excel 8.0;Database=d:\export\sales.xls;;HDR=YES', 
   'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
select * from sales_part1
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an in-depth tutorial on how to accomplish this in SSIS.](http://code-remind.blogspot.com/2013/03/ssis-sql-query-output-into-excel-tabs.html)

Specifically, look under **Package Overview** in their explanation.

4. Script Task:  The task labeled "Excel - Copy 1st tab of template and rename" does exactly that using VB.Net code. The script will connect to the excel template that was copied into the output folder.  It will take the 1st sheet/tab of the file, make a copy, move it to the end and rename the sheet according to the current value found in the Foreach Loop variable "Iterator_List_Item".
   Variables: Iterator_List_Item, Dest

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much Jonathan Porter! I really appreciate your help

Comment: @Please if this answers your question don't forget to mark it as an answer so that other people with this question can benefit!

Comment: I took the concepts from this article for my requirement. Stackoverflow is not allowing me to mark as answer as I recently signed up in this website.